# RestTemplate vs Apache Http Client for production code in spring project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

we have a Spring project that is about to go into production. Currently, the project is using `Apache Http Client`. There is a thought of using `RestTemplate` as `HttpClient`.

I am digging around to see any notable advantage of using `RestTemplate` over `Apache's`. Also, it would be interesting to know what HTTP transport does RestTemplate in its implementation. Apache Http Client has been used by several groups for many years and has a good reputation.

would we be risking moving to `RestTemplate`?

Further, this [blog](http://vincentdevillers.blogspot.com/2013/02/configure-best-spring-resttemplate.html) points that RestTemplate needs to be configured for production, although the configuration is minimal.

Thanks

Answer (score 92, accepted):

RestTemplate and HttpClient don't operate at the same abstraction level.

HttpClient is a general-purpose library to communicate using HTTP, whereas RestTemplate is a higher-level abstraction, dealing with JSON/XML transformation of entities, etc.

RestTemplate [delegates to a ClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#RestTemplate-org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory-), and [one of the implementations of this interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html) uses Apache's HttpClient.

So, if the goal is to communicate with a Restful API, and you still want to use HttpClient, you can use RestTemplate over HttpClient.

Note that what I just said is exactly what the blog you linked to explains:

> So, the solution is to use the org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, which is a ClientHttpRequestFactory delegating the creation of the requests to an HttpClient.

Comment: but what's the difference? they seem to provide the same function

Comment: @user2441441 Think of it like one those garden tools with a fancy handle where you can switch out the actual tool head from a rake to a hoe or something.  RestTemplate is the fancy handle which is nice to use.  It happens to come with a head installed, but you can switch out the head with something else.  In this case, the head is HttpClient, which you can use by itself, but it's a bit clunky, and it's good practice to use an abstraction.