# Does RestTemplate automatically release connection?

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am shifting my `REST` client module from `HttpClient.executeMethod(method)` to `RestTemplate.postForLocation(uri, obj)`. With the [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/), I would explicitly release the connection of the method:

> deleteMethod.releaseConnection();

I cannot find anything equivalent within the `Spring` [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). Does it automatically release connections? Another way to ask would be, I suppose, is it safe to not do anything after calling the `RestTemplate.postForLocation`?

Comment: This might answer your question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869193/using-spring-rest-template-either-creating-too-many-connections-or-slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the goals of spring templates is to make easy the things that are redundant. RestTemplate is not the exception and it manage the connection for you.

You can see more here.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html